# Is it possible to make a Swift Project Template including SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I was hoping to make a project template in order to speed up the development process for my next projects. But I have not found anything about how to make a project template to use `SwiftUI` for the setting for `User Interface` rather than `Storyboards`.

For example, here are the settings for the standard "Single View App".
[image]

However, when I use a custom project template I get the following options:
[image]

You'll notice that in the custom project template, there is no option for "User Interface".

Any ideas how I could add that option into my custom project template? I'm presuming there's probably something to add to the TemplateInfo.plist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitions Options:

[image: demo]

You can take one of a standard template (as I usually do) and tune it for your needs (ie. cut everything not SwiftUI related)

Eg. for Single View iOS App here

> Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project\ Templates/iOS/Application/Single\ View\ App.xctemplate

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to where that template is. I was able to figure out the rest from there!